# POI error openning excel after removing a sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to delete first sheet from the workbook (num of sheets > 1).

This is my code:

```
inputStreamExcel = new FileInputStream(path);
wrkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStreamExcel );

wrkbook .removeSheetAt(0);
outputStreamExcel = new FileOutputStream(path);             
wrkbook.write(outputStreamExcel );      
outputStreamExcel .flush();
outputStreamExcel .close();
```

I am not getting any exceptions.
But when I try to open the excel file I get an error:

> excel found unreadable content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the active sheet again after you remove the first sheet:

```
...
wrkbook.removeSheetAt(0);
wrkbook.setActiveSheet(0);
...
```

this should solve the problem.

Comment: I think it solved it, i will run more test scenarios before accepting this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when your excel has not been saved properly, 
probably you might want to check that while saving, the `current selected/active cell` is not pointing to a null row, or the `active sheet` is not null

Comment: what do you mean by active cell?

Comment: active cell means the current selected cell.also active sheet needs to be changed before/after (whatever works) deleting the current sheet